# Extreme slow connection to Client | CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, bandwidth, traffic

I have a CentOS 7 Server running on `centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64`

The problem is not the Client connection, neither the Server connection is.
But the connection between both is sadly slow.
The throughput is only 1/4 of the possible value when I got it right.

shell Command: `speedtest-cli`

Server-Internet:

```
Testing download
Download: 395.89 Mbit/s
Upload: 538.60 Mbit/s
```

result of: https://www.speedtest.net/ on a Chrome 64bit Windows 10

Client-Internet:

```
Download: 86.37 Mbit/s
Upload: 32.16 Mbit/s
```

linux-server command:`iperf3 -s`

windows-client command: `iperf3.exe -c "serverip"`

iperf3 connection check between both:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  28.2 MBytes  23.7 Mbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  28.1 MBytes  23.6 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

results of: `tracert server-ip`

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
  2     5 ms     6 ms     5 ms  62.155.240.4
  3     5 ms     6 ms     6 ms  217.239.50.106
  4     6 ms     5 ms     5 ms  217.239.50.106
  5     6 ms     5 ms    31 ms  lag-10.edge4.Berlin1.Level3.net [4.68.73.5]
  6    18 ms    18 ms    18 ms  ae-0-11.bar1.Munich1.Level3.net [4.69.153.253]
  7    18 ms    18 ms    18 ms  PROSIEBENSA.car1.Munich1.Level3.net [62.140.24.2]
  8    17 ms    17 ms    17 ms  vmd.server-ip.net [server-ip]
```

Comment: Im thankful for any suggestion

Comment: What did you use to ascertain the first two lots of figures? You might be comparing apples to peanuts.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I edited my question and added some information.
I tested on both servers the up and down with other web-sources and the numbers are acurate

Comment: And what iperf parameters are you using? Still looks like apples and peanuts to me .. ;)

Comment: I added the commands I just used the simpelst options

Comment: @tink can explain to me quick where I need to draw lines between different transfer speed measurements ?

Comment: I contacted my VPS Provider and they told me its probably ISP throttling from Telekom - will let you know if there is further informations